# How to write this in SQL?

Tags: sql, transactions

I have one table called Visit and another called Measurement. Primary key on Visit is vis_id and it is also foreign key in table Measurement. Now I would like to write a report based on data in table Measurement on following conditions:

Visit has field "itemAmount". I want only have data that has itemAmount = 2 in table Visit and both rows in Measurement related to Visit have measurement1 and measurement2 not null in table Measurement. If either one has either measurement1 or measurement2 NULL, then neither of the rows should be included.

How to do this? I know how to join and how to write simple conditions in where clause but I have no idea how to test this "couple feature", ie to test that BOTH rows related to Visit have both measurement1 and measurement2 different from null.

Comment: I wrote a bit incorrectly. There is one more table: "Item" and that one is related to Visit thru vis_id. Measurement is then related to Item thru Item_id that is pk in table Item and fk in table Measurement.

Comment: but the core of your query does not need Item table, does it?

Answer (score 0):

as a condition use:

```
WHERE itemAmount = 2
  AND measurement1 IS NOT NULL
  AND measurement2 IS NOT NULL
```

(if i understood you correctly)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what I'm trying to do is to test that both rows meet that condition (that you wrote above). I mean there is always two rows related to one row in Visit only if both meet the condition, then both will be included. Otherwise, either one of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample data is as you specified:

```
Visit:
vis_id      itemAmounts
----------- -----------
1           2
2           1

Item:
item_id     vis_id
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           2

Measurement:
item_id     measurement1 measurement2
----------- ------------ ------------
1           10           20
2           5            10
3           5            5
```

the query should be this one:

```
select  m1.*
from    Measurement m1
join    Item i1
    on  m1.item_id = i1.item_id
join    Visit v
    on  v.vis_id = i1.vis_id
    and v.itemAmounts = 2
join    Item i2
    on  v.vis_id = i2.vis_id
    and i1.item_id <> i2.item_id --//take the other item
join    Measurement m2
    on  i2.item_id = m2.item_id
    and m2.Measurement1 IS NOT NULL
    and m2.Measurement2 IS NOT NULL
where   m1.Measurement1 IS NOT NULL
    and m1.Measurement2 IS NOT NULL
```

or this one:

```
SELECT  m1.*
FROM    Measurement m1
JOIN    Item i
    ON  m1.item_id = i.item_id
JOIN   (SELECT      v.vis_id
        FROM        Visit v
        INNER JOIN  Item i
                ON  i.vis_id = v.vis_id
        INNER JOIN  Measurement m
                ON  m.item_id = i.item_id
                AND m.Measurement1 IS NOT NULL
                AND m.Measurement2 IS NOT NULL
        WHERE       v.itemAmounts = 2
        GROUP BY    v.vis_id
        HAVING      COUNT(*) = 2
        ) v_filter
    ON  i.vis_id = v_filter.vis_id
```

Both produce following result:

```
item_id     measurement1 measurement2
----------- ------------ ------------
1           10           20
2           5            10
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks, van! I tried this but it returns nothing:( If I delete the "and m1.ID <> m2.ID" row, it return two rows if both have mes1 and mes2. If either one has one of them null, it still returns the other one. Any advice? :)

P.S. I added the join to Item table because that's the only way to reference the Visit table to check the ItemAmount.

Comment: but this m1.ID <> m2.ID is very important. please post a sample of the data, and the expected output, as it is a bit not clear what exactly do you want and what exactly does not work

Comment: @Micke: added another option where the logic is to find all Visits for which Measurements should be displayed, and then display all measurements for it.

Comment: Ok, a simple example. Visit has two rows: Row1: vis_id 1, ItemAmount 2, Row2: Vis_id 2, ItemAmount 1. Table Item has three rows: Row1: Item_id 1, vis_id 1 Row2: Item_id 2, vis_id 1, Row 3: Item_id 3, Vis_id 2. Measurement has three rows, row1: item_id 1, measurement1 10, measurement2 20, row2: Item_id 2, measurement1 5, measurement2 10, Row3: Item_id 3, measurement1 5, measurement2 5. I want to as result get rows 1 and 2 from measurement because they both have mes1 and mes2 different from null and they are related (same vis_id and itemAmount = 2)

Comment: Addition. Visit table has also rows where itemamount is 3, 4 etc but those are unrelevant for this query. Also unlike in my example, table measurement has a lot of rows where measurement1 and/or measurement2 is null.